# Sorbet signature for a function with class argument?

Tags: ruby, sorbet

How do I write a signature for the following `archive_all` function?

[sorbet.run](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aextend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0Amodule%20Archivable%0A%20%20def%20archive%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0Aclass%20Book%0A%20%20extend%20Archivable%0Aend%0Aclass%20Magazine%0A%20%20extend%20Archivable%0Aend%0A%0Asig%20%7Bparams(klass%3A%20T.class_of(Archivable)).void%7D%0Adef%20archive_all(klass)%0A%20%20klass.archive%0Aend%0A%0Aarchive_all(Book)%20%0Aarchive_all(Magazine)%0A)

```rb
# typed: true
extend T::Sig

module Archivable
  def archive
  end
end
class Book
  extend Archivable
end
class Magazine
  extend Archivable
end

sig {params(klass: T.class_of(Archivable)).void}
def archive_all(klass)
  klass.archive
end

archive_all(Book) 
archive_all(Magazine)
```

Sorbet error:

```
editor.rb:17: Method archive does not exist on T.class_of(Archivable) https://srb.help/7003
    17 |  klass.archive
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    editor.rb:5: Did you mean: Archivable#archive?
     5 |  def archive
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Unless I horribly misunderstand how Sorbet works, I would assume that `class_of(Archivable)` is `Module`, and it is certainly true that not all instances of `Module` have a method named `archive`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be able to pass any instance of `Archivable`. The correct way to do this is to use a feature of Sorbet called a [*class type*](https://sorbet.org/docs/class-types):

```
sig {params(klass: Archivable).void}
```

[Observe](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aextend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0Amodule%20Archivable%0A%20%20def%20archive%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0Aclass%20Book%0A%20%20extend%20Archivable%0Aend%0Aclass%20Magazine%0A%20%20extend%20Archivable%0Aend%0A%0Asig%20%7Bparams(klass%3A%20Archivable).void%7D%0Adef%20archive_all(klass)%0A%20%20klass.archive%0Aend%0A%0Aarchive_all(Book)%20%0Aarchive_all(Magazine)%0A).